# Registering two singleton instances of same type using same interface

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I need to register two singleton instances of same type using same interface in Ninject,

for

```
kernel.Bind<IManifest>().To<Manifest>().InSingletonScope(); // first instance
kernel.Bind<IManifest>().To<Manifest>().InSingletonScope(); // second one
```

How can I achieve this? I hope there should be some way to differentiate them using some property or something..

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? Can you show and explain why you need two `Manifest` instances? How do you intend to you them?

Comment: I need two separate instances of same type to hold different application specific data..

Comment: I think, named binding should solve my issue https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface:-Referencing-Named-Bindings will give it a try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Named syntax:

```
kernel.Bind<IManifest>().To<Manifest>().InSingletonScope().Named("ManifestA");
kernel.Bind<IManifest>().To<Manifest>().InSingletonScope().Named("ManifestB");
```

Then retrieve it by calling:

```
kernel.Get<IWeapon>("ManifestA");
```

Or specify NamedAttribute in constructor.

```
public class ParentA
{
    public ParentA([Named("ManifestA")] IManifest manifest)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Then you can also use WhenInjectedInto syntax.

```
kernel.Bind<IManifest>().To<Manifest>().WhenInjectedInto<ParentA>().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IManifest>().To<Manifest>().WhenInjectedInto<ParentB>().InSingletonScope();
```

Or WhenParentNamed syntax if the Parents are of the same type:

```
kernel.Bind<Parent>().ToSelf().Named("ParentA");
kernel.Bind<Parent>().ToSelf().Named("ParentB");

kernel.Bind<IManifest>().To<Manifest>().WhenParentNamed("ParentA").InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IManifest>().To<Manifest>().WhenParentNamed("ParentB").InSingletonScope();
```